# Show Hide Issue in JQuery - CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="stage" >
<div id="stage_error" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></div>
<div id="stage_success" style="color:green;font-size:20px"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is my JavaScript with condition:**

```
  if(data != '') 
  { 
  $('#stage_error').html(data); 
  } 
  else 
  {        
  $('#stage_success').text('Registered Succesfully').show(100);
  $('#stage_error').hide();
  $('#stage_success').hide(3000);
  }
```

**Scene 1 :**

If the data is null, then it should show the success message - `#stage_success`

**Scene 2 :**

If the data has any value it show the first div error and then once the error is cleared, it should show the success message after hiding the error message `#stage_error`

**Issue :**

What I have the issue is once the success `#stage_success` is showed and then it's not displaying any error messages in the screen due to the #stage_error hidden

I guess `#toggle` is not correct way to do it.

Here is the value of data : It's getting value from external page:

```
Object {BusNo: Array[1], CompID: Array[1], TotalSeats: Array[1]}
```

### Is there any way I can handle this one?

Comment: What's the `data`? An ajax call or something? Then it'd be better to call that function inside succes or fail callbacks.

Comment: I probably don't get your question right, but $('#stage_error').show() before $('#stage_error').html(data) could be part of the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(data != '') 
  { 
  $('#stage_error').html(data).show(); 
  } 
  else 
  {        
  $('#stage_success').text('Registered Succesfully').show(100);
  $('#stage_error').hide();
  $('#stage_success').hide(3000);
  }
```

Just show the error whenever you put new data into it by adding a show();

Answer (score 1):

from your code I can understand you are handling some ajax success conditions or validation conditions
you can change you code in this way.

```
$('#stage_success, #stage_error').hide() // by default

if(data !== "" ){
      $('#stage_error').html(data).show();
} else {  
      $('#stage_success').text('Registered Succesfully').show(100);  
      $('#stage_error').html(''); 
      $('#stage_success').hide(3000);
}
```